# Number of ways to reach a node with minimum cost from a fixed node

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, dijkstra

There are n nodes(1,2.. n) in a `weighted graph` with m (m>n) `bi-directional edges`.

All weights are `positive` and there are `no multiple edges`.

There is `one fixed origin`(Node 1). We will always start traveling from the origin.

Now we have to find the `number of ways (path) to reach each of the nodes(starting from the origin) with minimum cost`.

`(All paths counted should have the minimum cost to reach that node from the origin)`.

Input — First line contains n,m.

Next m lines contain `u,v,w`. => There is an edge between u and v of weight w(w>0).

Output — Print n-1 lines one for each node other than origin, containing the number of ways to reach each of the nodes(starting from the origin) with minimum cost.

Sample Test -

4 5

1 2 5

1 3 3

3 2 2

3 4 7

2 4 5

Output —

2

1

3

Here is my solution, Please check if this will work for all cases, I did `Dijkstra + DP`. I am not sure about the correctness of the code.

```
#define pp pair<int,int>
vector< pp > adj[N]; //List to store graph
int dis[N],dp[N];

int main()
{
  ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
  int i,j,k,m,n,t;
  cin>>n>>m;
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
   int u,v,w;
   cin>>u>>v>>w;

   adj[u].push_back({w,v});       
   adj[v].push_back({w,v});
  }
priority_queue< pp , vector<pp > , greater<pp> > pq;   //Min Priority Queue
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++) dis[i] = INT_MAX;
dis[1] = 0;
dp[1] = 1;
pq.push({0,1});

while(!pq.empty())
{
  pp tp = pq.top();
  int u = tp.second;
  int d = tp.first;
  pq.pop();
  if(dis[u]<d) continue;       // We have better ans, so continue.

  for(i=0;i<adj[u].size();i++)  // Traversing all the egdes from node u 
    {
      int v = adj[u][i].second;  //Adjacent vertex v .
      int w = adj[u][i].first;
      if(d + w <= dis[v] )
       {
        if(d+w==dis[v])
        dp[v] += dp[u];     //Add the possible ways to the v from u

        if(d + w < dis[v])
          {
           dis[v] = d + w;  
           dp[v] = dp[u];   // Better ans so set it directly.
           pq.push({dis[v],v});  //Better ans found so push it into queue.
          }
       }
    }
 }

 cout<<endl;

 for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++)
 {
   cout<<i<<" dis = "<<dis[i]<<" ways = "<<dp[i]<<endl;
 }
 }
```

Comment: This may be more suitable for [codereview.se].

Comment: Having said that, your code is uncommented, some declarations are omitted and the identifiers are not self describing. It is not at all clear what your idea of a modification to Dijkstra is.

Comment: `adj[u].pb({w,v});
   adj[v].pb({w,v});` Are you sure this works? Like, at all?

Comment: Djikstra looks fine to me, I dont know what is troubling you @n.m. Although the code needs better indentation.

Comment: @n.m. Here is a link to my working code. http://ideone.com/89FvpD

Comment: @NikhilPathania it surely doesn't to me. It should add up the number of shortest paths to each vertex, but it looks like it adds the number of paths even if the new weight is smaller than the current one.

Comment: `if(d + w <= dis[v] )  dp[v] += dp[u];`  Does that means you count for those ways which does not achieve the final minimum cost `dis[v]`?

Comment: The first thing I see is that your C++ mastery is at "forget most of it and start over" level.

Comment: @NikhilPathania He is over counting something I think, if I were doing the same problem I would simply do Dijkstra and DP in two pass: first calculate the min cost of all `dis[]` and then use dp to add up those ways equal to the min cost

Comment: [Not so much working](http://ideone.com/fwXxw6)

Comment: @shole You are right, I was overcounting. I now have made some edits. Please check if this will work.

Comment: @AdityaN.K Okay now it is really getting closer to shift this problem into Code Review...btw why don't you just submit the solution and see how to judge respond? Or try some small test cases to test yourself

Comment: This trial-correction-new trial-correction cycle is not suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: [Not so much working 2](http://ideone.com/Qe2dwJ)

Comment: @shole This was a question asked in an interview. So, I can't submit it to judge.

Comment: Take your time to review *all* comments.

Comment: @shole how to move this question to Code review. Just Copy paste delete, or there is some other way.

Comment: @shole why, the Dijkstra part looks OK now.

Comment: @AdityaN.K there is still a bug in the input section.

Comment: @n.m. idk, but from the line  `if(d+w==dis[v]) dp[v] += dp[u];` and `if(d + w < dis[v])  dis[v] = d + w;` , wouldn't there be a chance that `dis[v]` updated after he add the counter `dp[v]`?

Comment: @shole no, don't think so. The conditions are complementary, exactly one of them is true. So either the counters are added or the distance is updated, but not both. It would be better to eliminate the second `if` check and put the body to the `else` part of the first `if`, but the current implementation still looks correct.

Comment: @n.m. OK i didn't read this `dp[v] = dp[u];`, I am sorry it's my bad. I am deleting my previous comment to prevent confusion

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating the problem by calculating both minimum distance and no. of pathways together.

- I think you first just run dijsktra normally and calculate minimum
  distances from source node to all the other nodes in one run
- Then, modify the current graph with existing bidirectional edges into uni-directional edges from node u -> node
  v, where `distance[v] >= distance[u]`  from source node S. This will result in a hierarchal graph with source S.
- After this u can just run either BFS or DFS from source node and
  count no. of ways of reaching that node by adding the no. of ways of reaching each parent node.